# Add custom function to render mustache template in golang using cbroglie

Tags: templates, go, mustache, google-app-engine-golang

I am using https://github.com/cbroglie/mustache for rendering mustache file.I want basically this example to work in go lang.But I guess custom function is not there.

```
Template:

{{#wrapped}}
  {{name}} is awesome.
{{/wrapped}
```

}

```
{
  "name": "Willy",
  "wrapped": function() {
    return function(text, render) {
      return "<b>" + render(text) + "</b>"
    }
  }
}
```

Output:

**Willy is awesome.**

Basically I want to use my custom defined function to render mustache in go.How is this possible can anyone tell me.

Comment: I don't see anywhere where it says it supports that in the docs or README, nor anywhere such functionality is described in [the moustache spec](https://mustache.github.io/mustache.5.html), where are you getting this from?

Comment: the moustache spec lambdas does that functionality but in go lang I am struggling.Syntax can be different.I am concerned over functionality.

Comment: Lamdas in the spec work absolutely nothing like what you described in the question.

Comment: @Adrian {{#wrapped}}
  {{name}} is awesome.
{{/wrapped}}   produces <b>Willy is awesome.</b>
 it takes wrapped as Utility function  without any binding context and produces o/p .I need similar functionality in golang.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see a direct way of doing this based on the documentation. But here's what i could get working. May be you can read more in the docs and try to get a better solution. Playground link [here](https://play.golang.org/p/5VUJKfXdhiW)

```
    package main

    import (
        "fmt"
        "strings"

        "github.com/cbroglie/mustache"
    )

    type CustomString string

    func (s CustomString) ToLower() string {
        return strings.ToLower(string(s))
    }

    func main() {
        out, err := mustache.Render(`Hey {{#myString}}{{ToLower}}{{/myString}}`, map[string]interface{}{"myString": []CustomString{CustomString("dEF")}})
        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }

        fmt.Println(out)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It works:

Playground [link](https://go.dev/play/p/v_AyoDV2wxy)

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "github.com/cbroglie/mustache"
)

func main() {
    template := `{{#wrapped}}{{name}} is awesome.{{/wrapped}}`

    funcRender := func(text string, render func(text string) (string, error)) (string, error) {
        text = "<b>" + text + "</b>"
        return render(text)
    }

    output, err := mustache.Render(template, map[string]interface{}{
        "name":    "Noel",
        "wrapped": funcRender,
    })

    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    fmt.Println(output)
}
```